# Mapping a expl3 clist to a list of command sequences

Tags: expl3, comma-separated-list, mapping

I am trying to map a clist to a clist of command sequences using \csname \endcsname and then using clist_use to print the list:

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\csI{}{Command~1}
\NewDocumentCommand\csII{}{Command~2}
\NewDocumentCommand\csIII{}{Command~3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\exin{m}{\dgmn_expressed_in:n { #1 }}

\cs_new:Npn \dgmn_expressed_in:n #1
{
\clist_clear_new:N \l_clist_abbs
\clist_put_left:Nn \l_clist_abbs { #1 }
\clist_remove_duplicates:N \l_clist_abbs
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_clist_abbs { \csname cs#1\endcsname }
\clist_use:Nnnn \l_clist_abbs { ~and~ }{ ,~ }{ ,~and~ }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
What I get:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \exin{I}
    \item \exin{II,I}
    \item \exin{II,I,III}
\end{itemize}

What I want:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \csI
    \item \csII\ and \csI
    \item \csII, \csI, and \csIII
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is the output:]

Comment: Not the core of the problem, but the code defines `\csA`, `\csB` and `\csC`. But `\exin` is called with arguments `I`, `II,I` etc. There seems to be no conversion between A, B, C and I, II, III.

Comment: In `\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_clist_abbs { \csname cs#1\endcsname }` you probably want `\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_clist_abbs { \csname cs##1\endcsname }` because what you want to turn into a control sequence is the implicit argument of `\clist_map_inline:Nn` and not the argument of the entire function (which is `#1`).

Comment: Together `\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_clist_abbs { \csname cs#1\endcsname }
\clist_use:Nnnn \l_clist_abbs { ~and~ }{ ,~ }{ ,~and~ }` don't have the desired effect. `\clist_map_inline:Nn <clist> {<code>}` applies the `<code>` to each item in the `<clist>`. It doesn't store the result, the code is executed directly. This means that the `\clist_map_inline:Nn` already prints the `cs`-ified list contents (if used as `\csname cs##1\endcsname`). The following `\clist_use:Nnnn` prints the list again.

Comment: I have a feeling that there might be a more `expl3`-y/elegant way to do this, so I won't write this up into an answer with working code. I'm sure an `expl3` wizard will drop by with a suggestion very soon.

Comment: Yea sorry i forgot to change the I, II, III to A,B,C before I sent it ;-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\exin` and `\dgmn_expressed_in:n` are not fully expandable; declaring them so doesn't change the fact.

You want first to map the comma list given as argument, populate the clist and then output it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\csI{}{Command~1}
\NewDocumentCommand\csII{}{Command~2}
\NewDocumentCommand\csIII{}{Command~3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\exin{m}
 {
  \dgmn_expressed_in:n { #1 }
 }

\clist_new:N \l_dmgn_abbs_clist

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dgmn_expressed_in:n #1
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l_dmgn_abbs_clist
  % map the input
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nx \l_dmgn_abbs_clist
     {
      \use:c 
       {
        cs ##1
       }
     }
   }
  \clist_remove_duplicates:N \l_dmgn_abbs_clist
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_dmgn_abbs_clist { ~and~ }{ ,~ }{ ,~and~ }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
What I get:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \exin{I}
    \item \exin{II,I}
    \item \exin{II,I,III}
\end{itemize}

What I want:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \csI
    \item \csII\ and \csI
    \item \csII, \csI, and \csIII
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First, thanks for the help!! Sorry, the mapping from alpha to roman was not really part of the problem, that was an oversight on my part. I have edited the MWE to change the original three commands to match the roman rather than the alpha.

Comment: @user39714 And I already changed my answer to be consistent with your change.